# Does closure remember reference or variable

Tags: javascript

I've read long ago that in JS a closure remembers reference a variable points at. If so, how does the following work?

```
var v = {a: 5};

function f1() {
   console.log(v); // outputs {a: 5}
    v = {b: 3};
}

function f2() {
    console.log(v); // outputs {b: 3}
}

setTimeout(f1, 1000);
setTimeout(f2, 2000);
```

I've changed the reference of the `v` variable, but the `f2` function shows the value from this new reference, instead of showing value from the old reference. How?

**EDIT:**

```
(function () {
    var v = {a: 5};

    function f1() {
        console.log(v); // outputs {a: 5}
        v = {b: 3};
    }

    function f2() {
        console.log(v); // outputs {b: 3}
    }

    f1();
    f2();
})();
```

**EDIT2:**

```
var f = (function () {
    var v = {a: 5};

    function f1() {
        console.log(v); // outputs {a: 5}
        v = {b: 3};
    }

    function f2() {
        console.log(v); // outputs {b: 3}
    }

    setTimeout(f1, 1000);

    return f2;
})();

setTimeout(function() {
    f();
}, 3000);
```

Comment: This is not related to closure in JS

Comment: There is no "old reference" vs "new reference". Both reference the same variable, and `f1()` just changes the value of that.

Comment: @connexo: That's what he's confused about. In non-functional languages, variables don't actually exist. That is, they are not objects themselves. They're just names we give things. And the value of a variable is the thing. In other words, the value of `v` is a reference. So when he says he's changing the reference he means the same thing as what you're saying: change the value. Closures work differently. It doesn't capture the thing/object but instead captures the variable itself.

Comment: @slebetman, yes, you're right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are just modifying and accessing a single global variable in your functions.  There is no lasting closure here.

Each `console.log(v)` simply outputs the current value of that global variable.

Your assignment to `v` in `f1()` just changes the value of the global `v`.

The `setTimeout()` operations are just complicating the story here.  You will achieve the same results with:

```
f1();
f2();
```

---

Here's an annotated view of what's happening:

```
// declare global variable v and initialize it
var v = {a: 5};

function f1() {
   // output current value of v
   console.log(v); // outputs {a: 5}
   // set v to a new value
   v = {b: 3};
}

function f2() {
    // output current value of v
    console.log(v); // outputs {b: 3}
}
```

So, if you unwrap the function calls, you have this sequence of code:

```
var v = {a: 5};
console.log(v); // outputs {a: 5}
v = {b: 3};
console.log(v); // outputs {b: 3}
```

---

In your second example, you've just moved the variable `v` into a common and shared parent scope.  The effect is still the same as both functions are accessing the same variable `v`.  What you have in this second example is a "scope" from the outer function (not a closure).  That scope survives for as long as the outer function is active and is thus shared by both `f1()` and `f2()` since they are within that scope.  Functions can access anything in their own scope or in their parent function's scope or in the global scope.

Keep in mind that a variable can directly contain a primitive value like `6` or `null`, but it points to object references (because assignment for objects is by pointer).  So when you access variable `v`, it is getting a pointer to the object that `v` currently contains and outputting that object.  When you later assign a new object to `v`, it just puts a different object pointer into `v` and when you access `v` again, it gets the pointer in `v` that points to that new object and outputs that object.  The variable `v` is the same in all cases, but the contents of `v` changes.

If you know a language like C/C++, then assigning an object to a variable in Javascript is like putting a pointer to that object in the variable's memory slot.  Unlike C/C++, pointers in Javascript are transparent (you don't have to know about them to use them), but that's essentially how they work (it's a little more complicated than that because there are reference counts too and runtime type information, but I'm just trying to give you the general idea).

Comment: @Maximus - You've just changed it to a commonly scoped variable.  The effect is exactly the same as when it was global, except instead of a global the variable is just in a parent scope that is shared by both functions.  The explanation is identical except you can substitute "global variable" with "commonly variable in a parent scope".  The point is that there's only one variable `v` that is being accessed by both functions.

Comment: So what you're saying is that, say variable `v` references slot `#101` in memory. When I change value like this `v={b:3}`, the variable continues to point to that slot, and JS engine changes data in memory at slot `#101`?

Comment: @Maximus - not really.  Variable `v` is the same variable for both your functions because it is in a parent scope and thus they both access the same variable.  When you do `v = {a: 5};`, variable `v` now points to that new object that you just created.  When you then later do `v = {b: 3};`, the variable `v` memory is updated to point at a different object.  Any time you do `console.log(v);`, it just gets whatever contents `v` has in it or points to and outputs that to the log.

Comment: Thanks, so then, in effect, closure remembers variable, not the reference?

Comment: @Maximus - your use of the term closure in this context has me baffled because there isn't really a lasting closure here.  There's a "scope" that contains `v`.  And, variables are contained within a scope and both `f1()` and `f2()` refer to the same variable `v` in their parent scope.  So, whenever you reference `v`, the code gets the current value of `v` which in this case is a pointer to an object.

Comment: I see, thanks. I think your last comment should be the answer, not the original one. Once you change it, I'll accept the answer

Comment: @Maximus - see what I added to the end of my answer.

Comment: thanks a lot for you help, yet it's not over :). After reading your comment about shared scope and the absence of the closure, it finally occurred to me that my 2nd example also didn't show what I was asking. Now, hopefully, the second edit should clearly demonstrate what I'm asking. Can you please take a look?

Comment: @Maximus - I must say that your question is a lot of work :) - 3rd version now.  Your third version is indeed a closure.  All the closure adds to the question is that the scope I previously described lasts beyond the containing function's regular execution.  Everything else is identical.  The variable `v` is in a parent scope and the assignment to the variable `v` all works the same.   I think of a closure as just a scope that still has live references so it isn't garbage collected yet (e.g. it lasts longer).  Other than that, it works just like any other scope.

Comment: Got you! Thanks a lot for bearing with me! Best of luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

When you create a variable in a blocked scope using

```
v = {b: 3};
```

Like the way you have done in

```
function f1() {
   console.log(v); // outputs {a: 5}
    v = {b: 3};
}
```

It will always change the global reference to it

```
function f1() {
       console.log(v); // outputs {a: 5}
       var v = {b: 3}; // this creates a variable in this scope
    }
```

Comment: Though, you should be clear that using global and local variables of the same name is generally bad form in nearly every programming language.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your variable **v** is in global scope.So it will be available in both function **f1** and **f2** and any change in that will available in both functions.

Here is example : http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/javascript/aKEQ220913-Understanding-Local-and-Global-Variables-in-JavaScript.html

Answer (score 0):

First of all **V** is the global object so whether you change from the **f1 or f2 function** **whenever you will change the value by reference to the object v's value it will globally changed**...!!